# Seeking Mevaseret Sion

Tags: jewish-books

On Doresh-Tzion.co.il I see Rav Mutzafi Shelit"a quoting his book "Mevaseret Tzion" many times (and I also hear Rav Meir Eliyahu Shelit"a quote it). Does anyone know where I can purchase this book?

Comment: You can view it on Otzar Hachochma -- the first 40 pages are available for free. See here: http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/Book.aspx?23222&

Comment: I see that the sefer lists the address of "Yeshivat Benei Tzion" in Yerushalayim, so presumably you could get a copy from there. If you're in NY, try Biegeleisen at 718-436-1165.

Comment: @Dave may I suggest writing your comments as an answer?

Comment: @avi - I don't really *know* where he can buy this sefer, my suggestions are just informed conjecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Sefer is available by calling any of the following numbers. http://doresh-tzion.co.il/BooksSale.aspx

0525-454787  פתח תקווה

0528-936011  אלעד

0548-033817  ירושלים - הר חוצבים

0504-150877  ירושלים - בית וגן קרית יובל

0503-500750  ירושלים - בית ישראל

0504-154140  חיפה

0544-646882  כרמיאל .. מגדל העמק

0504-198997  טבריה

0523-386231  נהריה

0504-245474  נתניה

0528-778282  בני ברק

0525-935655  אשדוד

0544-807659  אשקלון

0522-751941  ראשל״צ

0509-002097 לוד

0522-751941 מודיעין

0522-751941 רחובות

0527-642912 עכו

0504-112626 בית שמש

03-6560330   משרד

0522-751941  אלירן

0503-500750  חיים

Comment: An absurdly exhaustive answer! +1

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know if they internationally?